# Write the meta-FAQ

Tags: discussion

we are already writing a [site-faq](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-faq). Should we also write an meta-[faq](/questions/tagged/faq)?

Most pages have a meta-[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) for example [StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow), [MetaStackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

We already have a few good posts like

- [Standard Notation](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/standard-notation)
- [Why does the Quantum Computing site look different?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-does-the-quantum-computing-site-look-different)
- [Tutorial: How to use TeX/MathJax?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax)
- [How to handle questions that relate to "quantum", but not "computing"?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-to-handle-questions-that-relate-to-quantum-but-not-computing)
- [Are questions about Q# on topic?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-questions-about-q-on-topic)
- [Are resource request questions allowed?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-resource-request-questions-allowed)

(list unsorted)

Comment: Hmm, that [faq](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag seems to be a mod-only tag. Perhaps just as we are doing for the main site faq questions, as for now, just compile a list of the questions you want to be in the faq (we can discuss in chat) as answers to this post. Later we will ask the mods to add the faq tags to them.

Comment: I added the `meta-faq` tag since `faq` is mod-only.  I suppose a mod can retag 'em later.

Comment: @Nat Good! Maybe leave a comment on the other posts where you want the meta-faq tag to be added, in that case.

Comment: I have suggested a tag info to [meta-faq](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-faq/info) tag for those who have not seen this discussion. Pls vote for the tag info and/or help editing it.

Comment: @bytebuster According to the [privileges page](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), it takes 750 rep to approve tag wiki edits, so there's currently only one person around with that privilege, so it can take a few hours before edits are accepted

Comment: @Mithrandir24601, there are also Global Moderators who do that before the pro-tem Mods are appointed.

Comment: @bytebuster That's exactly who that 'one person' (Robert)  is ;)

Comment: It makes sense to have two FAQs since some SE sites have different Rep levels on Main vs. Meta. There's a different workload Main vs. Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/should-reputation-from-so-carry-over-to-meta/63235#63235 and different things we want done on each site. – Our site has hourly synchronization ATM: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta but that could change.